# Android Youtube api View Pager issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am using a viewpager to load youtube videos which using FragmentPagerAdapter to feed Youtube fragment to the viewpager. The problem i am having is that the first youtube video loads and the rest does'nt.

Here is the method in my HomeFragment that creates the viewpager

```
public void setupUI(View view)
{
   // viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(),rank,country,population,flag);
    FragmentActivity fragact = myContext;



    FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(fragact.getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);

    //pager_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, rank, country, population, flag);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    //viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    CirclePageIndicator titleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    titleIndicator.setViewPager(viewpager);
}
```

Here is my fragment adapter

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {

    super(fragmentManager);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    String test = Integer.toString(position);
    ImageFragment imgfrag = ImageFragment.newInstance(test,test);
    return imgfrag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
}
```

Here's the fragment that loads youtube video

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private YouTubePlayer activePlayer;
public static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";



// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment ImageFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static ImageFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}



public ImageFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY,this);
    //FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    //android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment,youTubePlayerFragment,YouTubePlayerFragment.class.getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    RootView.findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return RootView;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

        youTubePlayer.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
    Log.v("Youtube", "Success occured one");


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    String errorMessage = String.format("error reason", youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }
}

protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YouTubePlayerFragment.class.getSimpleName());
}


/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Here is my logcat

```
08-26 13:22:11.020      348-348/com.festivalguide.v2.edmx E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity com.festivalguide.v2.edmx.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@1dd9bd3c that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.festivalguide.v2.edmx.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@1dd9bd3c that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1077)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:971)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1774)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
```

Help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem, not is the "rest" not work, only works 1 first time, I don't know why, I need find a solution (reload instance or I don't know) if you close app, same works the first time

Comment: @delive did you find solution ??

Comment: yep convert to Activity :S is so bad, but documentation works with fragment or activity (not work fragment into fragment)

Answer (score 1):

//I think releasing the fragment in on Pause is the thing you are missing

@Override
    public void onPause() {

```
    super.onPause();
    if (youTubePlayerFragment != null) {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove(getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourcontainerid))
                .commit();

    }
    Player.release();
}
```

Comment: This worked surprisingly well for me,Only that i did it in `setUserVisibleHint()` since i was using it in a viewpager