# Fragment Destroy completely YouTube

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

When I load YouTube first time Works well, but when I try reload page, yotube always waiting ...

This error is because "Fragment" not destroy completly. if you close App, Works well first time.

My question is How I can destroy completely fragment ?

```
public class YoutubeFragment extends Fragment {
    // API キー
    private static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    // YouTubeのビデオID
    private static String VIDEO_ID = "EGy39OMyHzw";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.you_tube_api, container, false);

        // YouTubeフラグメントインスタンスを取得
        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

        // レイアウトにYouTubeフラグメントを追加
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

        // YouTubeフラグメントのプレーヤーを初期化する
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {

            // YouTubeプレーヤーの初期化成功
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                    player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                    player.play();
                }
            }

            // YouTubeプレーヤーの初期化失敗
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
                // YouTube error
                String errorMessage = error.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

YouTube simple : https://gist.github.com/takeshiyako2/e776bbaf2966c6501c4f

Related : [Android Youtube api View Pager issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221826/android-youtube-api-view-pager-issue)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?  Calling Release does not seem to be enough. In my case, it works the first three times. Then it starts to fail with error "There was a problem while playing. Tap to retry".

Answer (score 0):

Dont destroy the fragment. Just make sure you are releasing the player.

Call  YPlayer.release();//YPlayer as an instance variable of player

Do this in onPause of your fragment.